# JQuery load div with submitted form data

Tags: php, jquery, load

hi i want to load a div from load.php page into my index.php page with submitted form data but i get only  with only text (form values not loaded) so here is the code
index.php:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#result').load('load.php #load');
    });
</script>

    <div id="result" ></div>
```

load.php:

```
<div id="load">Emotions that causes your project <?php echo $test;?></div>
```

but it give me:

```
<div id="result">Emotions that causes your project</div>
```

so it doesn't echo $test variable on my #result div, so can u suggest me how can i get it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) initiates a separate [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) request (a.k.a. `$ajax()` call).

Being separate, this request has no implicit direct relation with the rest of your php's application logic and has no connection with the initial request that composed the page you are on.

If you need `$test` variable to be populated, you have to define and populate it in your `load.php` script (or include other `.php` files that populate it).

Place this in your `load.php` to test:

```
<?php $test = 'test'; ?>
<div id="load">Emotions that causes your project <?= $test;?></div>
```

Please note `.load()` allows you to pass data with the request, which you could use in `php` to generate the response. For example, the request which sends data to server:

```
 $('#result').load('load.php #load', {"foo":"bar"});
```

... and get+use that data in `load.php`:

```
<?php $test = $_REQUEST['foo']; ?>
<div id="load">Emotions that causes your project <?= $test;?></div>
```

Of course, you could replace `foo` and `bar` with whatever you need. Use jQuery to get the data from input elements in your page.

Comment: i just tried your suggestion but it's only replace <?= $test;?> with value test, so it's not a variable. because i got value of $test from a form submit, and it's always changing(variable).

Comment: @Mouhssine `$test` is a variable. If the value should be set based on user interaction with your page, you must send that information to `load.php` in your `.load()` request, using the second parameter (see the link I provided in answer). You can `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what was sent and get your data from there. But you must send the data. otherwise you cannot use it inside `load.php`. I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of searching i solved my problem so there is how:
home.php:

```
<?php 

    $test = $_POST['test']; 

?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#result').load('load.php?test=<?php echo urlencode($test);?> #load');
    });
</script>

<div id="result" ></div>
```

then on my load.php:

```
<?php 

    $test = $_GET['test']; 

?>

<div id="load">Emotions that causes your project <?= $test;?></div>
```

so i get $test value on my loaded content on #result, it's all.